# Count linked follow up ids in SQL and add them to a list

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and am having trouble figuring out how to do this. I have a table with id's and follow-up id's. I'm trying to figure out how many ids are linked to each other. I'm unsure the maximum amount of links in my table. The follow-up id column is null if there is no follow-up. For example my table looks like this:

```
id | follow-up id
a  | null
b  | d
c  | f
d  | null
e  | null
f  | g
g  | null
```

and I'd like my new table to focus on the inital ids (ids that are not follow-ups) and look like:

```
initial_id | count | linked_id_list
a          |   1   |    a
b          |   2   |   b, d
c          |   3   |  c, f, g
e          |   1   |    e
```

I'm honestly unsure of how to go about this. I know some kind of loop with counters and updating which id to go to next.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh trino I think.

Comment: you should know what system you are using as different systens you differebt syntax

Comment: recursive SQL query will help

Comment: @nbk It is trino SQL.

Answer (score 0):

See example. There recursive query ( tested with SQL Server and Postgres, and I can't say  about your Trino).
You can start with this.

```
with r as ( -- anchor part of recursive query - ids that are not follow-ups
select 0 level,id initial_id
  ,1 as qty
  ,cast(id as varchar(100)) as followers
  ,id next_follow_up_id
from test t
where -- ids that are not follow-ups
   not exists(select id from test t2 where t2.follow_up_id=t.id)

union all

select level+1,initial_id
  ,r.qty+1 as qty
  ,cast(followers +','+ t.follow_up_id as varchar(100)) as followers
  ,t.follow_up_id as next_follow_up_id
from r inner join test t on t.id=r.next_follow_up_id
where t.follow_up_id<>r.initial_id
  and level<7 -- this is for debug only
)
select initial_id,qty,followers 
from (
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by initial_id order by level desc) rn
  from r
  )ranked 
where rn=1
```